# .htaccess remove folder paths in REQUEST_URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess

While reading through countless answers on here I can't seem to find one that works. The task is pretty simple: remove `/fldr/subfldr/` from the REQUEST_URI while still always redirecting to index.php. fldr and subfldr are real directories while everything after does not really exist. The .htaccess and index.php are sitting within subfldr.

The current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [PT,L]
```

And other RewriteRules I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/fldr/subfldr/?.*$ index.php [PT,L]
```

I've even tried just adding the folders to the RewriteBase. Every version passes the exact same thing through to the request.

Comment: Have you considered redirecting the browser to a URL that removes the `/fldr/subfldr/` bit? Then the request would come to the server without it.

Comment: @JonLin Wouldn't that mean moving index.php to the root dir? That isn't really an option unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, is everything in a physical /fldr/subfldr/ directory?

Comment: @JonLin Yes it is! Those are the only two physical directories. Then from there on is purely MVC params etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to rewrite the REQUEST_URI environment variable, try just passing a 'uri' param or something to the script, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fldr/subfldr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?uri=$0
```

Then you can use $_GET['uri'] in index.php.

Answer (score 1):

Try this then (htaccess file is in your `/fldr/subfldr/` directory):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /fldr/subfldr/

# pass through if already index.php
RewriteRule index\.php - [L]

# Rewrite to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

This *should* make it so the `REQUEST_URI` that's passed to index.php has the `/fldr/subfldr` part of the path removed.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't do anything. This still passes /fldr/subfldr/ as the REQUEST_URI. The .htaccess is definitely being read however. The index.php redirecting works perfect.